# OnTriggerEnter play only once as on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is my compulsion to use **rigidbody and box collider** to all collided gameObjects  (Where I have to detect collision)., i.e., I got some really big trouble
 as tw**o object collide with each other, 2 times onTriggerEnter play** which I surely don't want to do. Is there any way to control it.? Without removing Script
 and rigidbody to any object.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collidedAGV)
    {

     if (collidedAGV.tag == "cib" )
     {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad - in the first instance you should familiarize yourself with the **Layers** feature in Unity -- it's great.  In fact you have to use it every time.

Comment: u mean i need to change the layer then, check triggger but i will be unable to reset it. i guess

Comment: it's worth mentioning that, in theory, one thing you *can* do in that type of situation is get the `InstanceID` of both and only act if you are the lower ID!  i wouldn't really recommend that as a solution here http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html

Comment: why u will not recommend

Comment: I have use layer it working fine but i didn't test it correctly! so maybe layer solution look feasible but have to test vigorously

Answer (score 0):

You could either change the tag of one of the objects, or make the script also check the name of object it has collided to:

```
void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider collidedAGV )
{
    if (collidedAGV.tag == "cib" && collidedAGV.name == "collided object name")
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not feasible for me

Comment: Can you explain why?